# Multiple of a number and sum of a set

Tags: number-theory, circles

Lets say there is a number `30`, and this sum of numbers

```
3 + 5 + 7 + 9 ...
```

Now I want to find where this sum and a multiple of 30 gets equal.

for `30` its `4` = `30 * 4 = 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 + 17 + 19 + 21`

I don't have any math experience, just wanted to know if this could be calculated by some formula.

I can imagine, that it must somehow be related to circles/sine-waves, where 30 is the length of the circle and the sum of this numbers must somehow match a multiple of it.

Maybe there is some kind of formula for this already, would like to know, thanks

PS: would be nice, if you could also put the right tags to this question

Comment: 30 the length of the circle ?? What do you mean

Comment: I mean the radiant of the circle, if the circle has the radius of 30/2π, then the radiant is 30

Comment: Okay. from where you get this question?  add details because it seems this appears somewhere you want to solve a certain problem in a certain way.

Comment: It's a part of my research in the field of number-theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that the sum of first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$ . So the sum $$1+3+5+\cdots+(n+1) = n^2 \\ \implies 3+5+7+\cdots+(n+1)=(n+1)^2-1$$Since we want it to be a multiple of $30$ , We have the following equation:

$$(n+1)^2- 1= 30k \implies n^2+2n-30k = 0$$

Using quadratic formula , we get:

$$n = \dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{4+120k}}2\implies n = -1+\sqrt{1+30k}$$

Since $n$ is an integer , it follows that $(1+30k)$ must be a perfect square of an odd number.

$$1+30k = (2x+1)^2 \implies k = \dfrac{2x(x+1)}{15}$$

Since $2$ is not divisible by $15$ , it follows that $x^2+x\equiv 0\mod 15$
and we get the possible values of $x \equiv 0,5,9,14 \mod 15$ $($The proof is left to the readers .$)$

Our previous equation becomes ,

$$n = -1 + 2x+1 \implies n = 2x$$

So for $x \equiv 0,5,9,14 \mod 15$ , you can get a possible solution $$(n,k) = \left(2x , \dfrac{2x(x+1)}{15}\right)$$

Comment: This answer is missing the most illuminating part: which values of $x$ actually produce an integer, which is central to OP’s question.

Comment: @ErickWong Better now ?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  The OP might need to familiarize themselves with mod notation, but this answer is self-contained.

Comment: @ErickWong In the comments section , he has written that this is *a  part of my research in the field of number-theory* so I believe they might be familiar with this notion.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit this looks precise. Any idea, why the k cannot be `> m/4`?

Comment: @webdeb Can you explain what is $k > m/4$ ?

Comment: for any `m` like `30` the `k` is not larger then `m / 4`, (I created a script and tested some values, k never went higher then a 1/4 of the actual number `m`)

Comment: @webdeb Well , for $m = 30$ , $k  = 12$ and $n = 18$ works. As I showed  , there are infinite solutions for $n,k$.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I mean the minimal k was always < m/4

Comment: @webdeb This really should be a new question.

Answer (score 3):

First you should know the sum of arithmetic series.  The
arithmetic series general term is $a_n=a_1 +(n-1)r,$ where $r$ is the base the constant you add with every term. 
The sum of the first $n$ terms is given by 
$$S_n= na_1+r(1+2+\cdots +(n-1))=na_1 +\frac{r n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(2a_1+r(n-1))}{2}.$$
In our case $a_1=3, r=2.$
So we want $n$ such that

$$\frac{n(2a_1+r(n-1))}{2}=30k.$$

Hence

$$\frac{n(4+2n)}{2}=30k$$
$$n(4+2n)=60k$$
$$n(2+n)=30k$$ we want first $n$ such that the left hand side is multiple of $30$ we know that $30$ contains $2,3,5$ so you need to make the left hand side contains these primes and $10$ is good because it contains $2,5$ and the $10+2$ contains the $3$ . If $n$ is 10 then $k=4$

Arthimatic series is a series begin with a number and you add a constant with each term ( the difference between conseqetive numbers is a constant ) . To find the formula for the sum we depend on the sum of $1+2+3+\cdots +n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: Ah, I see, the arthimatic series makes sense, but how to use it, to find the **k** for any number? like f(30) => 4, f(24) => 2

Comment: N=20 also works

Comment: Interesting, but without finding the prime factors of 30, there no way to get the k, straightforward right?

Comment: By guessing!  try $n=1,2,3,4,\cdots$

Comment: Hmm, like I wrote in the question, I can imagine this to be related to circles. Is there something that we can use?

Comment: n=30 works, k=32, and n=28.

Comment: @webdeb In general, finding the zeros of a quadratic mod $m$ is at least as difficult as factoring $m$.  That’s because if you can find a sufficient number of solutions then you can use them to factor the number.

Comment: @ErickWong got it, so there can't be an efficient formula for this